# Why isn't ajax updating my text field on this form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I have a "Resend activation" form on my site. Basically the visitor enters their email address and I resent the original activation email.

The problem is, if they enter an email address and click submit, then enter a different email address (i.e. they mis-typed their original email) then it still just uses their first input.

Here's the code:

```
// *****************************************************
// CHECK FORM WHEN TRYING TO RESEND ACTIVATION
// *****************************************************

$('#form-resend-activation').on('submit', function(e){
$('#formTitleText').text(ajax_login_object.loadingmessage);

    var error = false;
    // Declare the function variables - parent form, form URL and the regex for checking the email
            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

   // Start validation by selecting all inputs with the class "required"

      if($('#username').val() == ''){
          $('#username').addClass('error');
          $('#formTitleText').text("Please enter an email address");
          error = true;
      }


        // Run the email validation using the regex for those input items also having class "email"
                if(!emailReg.test($('#username').val())){
              $('#username').addClass('error');
              $('#formTitleText').text("Enter a valid email address");
              error = true;
      }



        // All validation complete - check whether any errors exist - if not submit form
 if (!error) {
        $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url:ajax_login_object.ThemeFolder+ajax_login_object.auxFunctionsFolder+"/check_login_details.php",
                    data: { 
                        'username': $('#username').val(),
                        'originatingPage': ajax_login_object.redirecturl,
                        'resend_activation': true,
                        'security': $('#security').val() },                   
                        success:function(data){
                            if(data.done_successfully == true) {
                                // THIS HAS HAPPENED SUCCESSFULLY
                                $('#formTitleText').html("<div class='login_message_box'><img src='"+ajax_login_object.ThemeFolder+"/images/loginbox/tick.png' class='JTloginFormImage'> "+data.message+"</div>");
                            } else {
                                // THIS HAS NOT HAPPENED BECAUSE THEY AREN'T IN THE DATABASE
                                $('#formTitleText').html("<div class='login_message_box'><img src='"+ajax_login_object.ThemeFolder+"/images/loginbox/cross.png' class='JTloginFormImage'> "+data.message+"</div>");
                            }
                        }
        });
    }
        e.preventDefault();
});
// *****************************************************
// END OF RESEND ACTIVATION FORM
// *****************************************************
```

If anyone has any ideas regarding this then I would be all ears. I'm a newbie to jquery so only really finding my way through it. Many thanks

John ;-)

Comment: What are you using to build the activation form? is it static, or in a dialog, or being loaded with ajax, etc

Comment: Hi Kevin, The form is static. There's actually 3 forms, all with unique #id's. One for logging in, then if the ajax detects that it's an unknown email addy it 'hides' the login form and opens the Registration form. If the email that is entered is in the database (but not activated) then it opens the activation form.